# Alternative for Apple Books

Tags: ebooks, epub, ipad

We are doing a project in which the .epub files are generated using windows inhouse built applications and being verified using Apple Books application in Apple Ipad(5th gen). We have more number of windows machines but having less number of Ipad tablets and transferring data to ipad from windows is also taking more time.

Hence I wanted to do the same visual check on windows machine instead of Ipad. But so far I haven't found any suitable Epub readers that is quite similar to Ipad. Windows reader reads .epub files but the alignment issues shown in Ipad are not shown in Windows readers precisely. I have tried Calibre and FBreader, both of them are opening .epub files but alignment not displaying same as Ipad. Is there any possibility to view .epub files similar to Apple Ipad in Windows machine?